# update value of <apex:repeat>

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

is there any possibility to update list to iterate in apex:repeat markup?
I tried to do this in javascript, but without success. I have some data in JS by calling externall service, and after that I want to update apex:repeat by this data.

Comment: update the list in controller and rerender this `apex:repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first part you can update the list in controller and rerender this `apex:repeat`.

Second point check if in `javascript` you are getting updated value or if not then put that script in some panel and `rerender` that panel.